# XSS on a login page

Tags: asp.net, security, xss

This is a theoretical question.

Suppose I have a login page with three elements on it: username textbox, password textbox, log in button. I sanitize the input and enable request validation in the config.

In what ways can the site can still be vulnerable to XSS? (assume that no other page on the site can be accessed by a non-authenticated user)

Answer (score 2):

XSS is not a threat for static state. XSS is a threat where content from a malicious user is able to be viewed by other users.

A simple example is a Facebook post or Twitter post that maliciously embeds javascript so that it executes when others view it on their time line.

In an individual static page this is not a threat. The way it can be a threat is if the page has commenting capabilities that users can enter content. The other way XSS becomes a threat is they register themselves perhaps with a description or user name that is a javascript string. You present a page that lists the newest registered users and now their javascript becomes active on the page.

## If users cannot get content into your page, XSS cannot occur.

Things to be concerned about is any time you take raw output onto the page, whether it comes from the querystring or from an unowned server. If someone can replace your copy of jquery that's hosted on a CDN with a malicious jquery, that will introduce XSS.

Note for the first page that ASP.NET and IIS go a very long way in protecting you from XSS. If you do not disable security features of ASP.NET and IIS the majority of all vectors are protected from a user ever submitting malicious code to your server. That's not to say it is impossible, but the built in protections are very robust... unless you disable them.

Answer (score 1):

There would be no XSS on a simple page; unless you use javascript to parse page arguments and embed them into the page (say, "Wrong password for email@address.com", where email@address.com is from the input field and is not sanitized properly).